# How to save location hash state when browser reload

Tags: javascript

all. I'm using livereload which is autoreload html,js file tool.

It is very convenient.But I have one problem. I am making single web page app which is depends on hash change website. 
Like this . /#/home, /#/product. So when reload browser at /#/product it reloads and back to root / url.It's difficult to debug.

I want to save hash location when reload browser. If I reload /#/product page , and I want to stay still at /#/product page.

Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using a real hash in `/#/home`. Use `/#home` or `/#product` and it will persist  on reload.

Answer (score 0):

When your page is loaded, you need to have javascript code that runs that examines the current hash value and constructs the right page state that matches that hash value.  Then, when your page is reloaded, the base page will load from the server and then your code will run and see that `#/product` hash value and construct the appropriate page for that hash value.